# Using CASE WHEN in Mysql

Tags: mysql

Given the following sample table containing data about stocks:

| Date | Symbol | Close |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-09-05 | ABC | 100 |
| 2022-09-05 | DEF | 50 |
| 2022-09-06 | ABC | 120 |
| 2022-09-06 | DEF | 60 |
| 2022-09-07 | ABC | 132 |
| 2022-09-07 | DEF | 66 |

I want to make a query about the performance of each asset against the previous  day close
Here is my code and let's say today is 2022-09-07:

```
SELECT curr.Symbol, 100.0*(curr.close - prev.close) / prev.close As PercentDiff
FROM (SELECT * FROM sample.mytable WHERE Date = (SELECT CURDATE()))  As curr
JOIN (SELECT * FROM sample.mytable WHERE Date = (SELECT CURDATE()-1)) As prev
ON curr.Symbol = prev.Symbol;
```

Here's the result (don't mind the decimal formatting ):

| Symbol | PercentDiff |
| --- | --- |
| ABC | 10.00000 |
| DEF | 10.00000 |

But let's say a new stock named GHI gets listed on 9/7/2022 so there will be no calculated result on the PercentDiff field.  How do I return it with the result returned as "null"?

Just a newbie here. Just want to ask if using the CASE WHEN statement is the right approach and how do I incorporate it in my code?

Comment: Hi, and welcome to dba.se! What version of PostgreSQL are you using?

Comment: Im using mysql 8

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73495778/calculate-daily-percent-change-in-mysql) on SO! Please **don't** cross-post duplicates - forum shopping isn't allowed. Choose one and if you can't get a reply (after a couple of days), post elsewhere referring back to your original question!

Comment: It is not a duplicate, this is  kind of a variation of that question though. In the original, I was asking a running total for the percentdiff column. However, the actual table I'm gonna query has tens of millions of rows in it so it's impractical for me to query it that way. What I intend now to do is to calculate only the percent change for the current date against the past day but i'm also planning to expand it to other  date points like past month, past quarter etc. which I already know as I already put the code in the question to get those results

Comment: My problem is that some of the stocks had no previous data on their dates because they are recently listed and I want my query to return "NULL" on the percentdiff field which I think will be solved by a CASE WHEN statement but I don't know how to incorporate it in my code. Btw, I am restricted on posting in stack overflow so

Comment: As asked, it was a duplicate. After I answered, you changed the goalposts `from previous day` by then (in comment) asking about `vs a date in the past... past 1 or 7 days, past month or 3 months,`. LAG()/LEAD() will provide you with the necessary `NULL`s - as for your table having millions of records, that is neither here nor there - if you do a `CASE...`, you're also going to be paying an overhead. The internals of the Postgres source code are a bit above my pay grade, but I'd bet that it's fairly well optimised. I don't know why you think LAG() is any worse than a CASE expression. Benchmark?

Comment: Ask a new question, referring back to your previous one(s). Be clear about it **not** being a dup! Also, please construct fiddles with your sample data - it's a courtesy to those who are answering, eliminates duplication of effort on our part and provides a SPOT - single point of truth for the question.

Comment: Got it. Newbie programmer here. Still learning the ropes. Anyway,  I think you misunderstood me. I know how to modify my code to calculate the percentdiff be it past week, month etc. It's just that about setting the pecentdiff to null if there is no previous data. Your answer returns three columns. What I want is just two columns: the symbol and percentdiff(it was a daily query) Regardless, I was able to formulate a workaround.

Comment: Hint:  No subqueries are needed.  Just JOINs and aliases.